# Workaround to create custom Compose shadows?

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

I'm aware of the issues the community has opened with Google over lack of good Shadow API support: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/160665122

Does anyone have a solution that works on all devices (not just 28+) to fake a customizable Shadow in Compose? Maybe using Canvas, Bitmap? Frustrating that this issue has not been addressed.

Tried using the newer Compose Shadow Modifiers, and still is not customizable enough.